# C++ FILE pointer to stdout?

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program and I want the user to be able to specify whether the output is written to a file or to stdout.  Until this point, my program has been using printf commands, so I was hoping to simply change the commands to fprintf commands, but my compiler is shouting at me because obviously, they are not the same object classes.

For example:

```
FILE *fp;
bool print_to_file;
.
.
.
if(print_to_file){
  fp = fopen("something.txt", "w");
}
else{
  fp = &stdout;
}
fprintf(fp,"%s\t%s\t%s\n",string1 . c_str(), string2 . c_str(), string3 . c_str());
```

I'd prefer to stick with fprintf and find a FILE pointer to stdout, does anyone know if that's possible?  If the answer is no, can I open my files as fstreams, and then use fprintf?

Comment: Of course, in idiomatic C++ you'd use a `ostream&` that references either `std::cout` or a `std::ofstream`

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`stdout` is a `FILE*`, so you can simply use:

```
FILE* fp = stdout;
```

Comment: Thanks!  Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 7):

Just drop the ampersand: `fp = stdout;`.